# CSS/ file is properly linked but, when I try to change the colors of the ID elements inside the CSS nothing happens. Any ideas?

Tags: php, css

This is modalpopup.php

```
<h1>Pop Up</h1>
<button id="openBtn">Show Pop Up</button>
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="modal">
    <button id="closeBtn">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="js/modalpopup.js"></script>
```

This is javascript.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Projects</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript.php?counter">Counter App</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.php?randomnumber">Random Number Generator</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.php?hexgenerator">Color Generator</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.php?popup">Pop Up</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['counter'])){
  include('counter.php');
}if(isset($_GET['randomnumber'])){
  include('randomnumber.php');
}if(isset($_GET['hexgenerator'])){
  include('hexgenerator.php');
}if(isset($_GET['popup'])){
  include('modalpopup.php');
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is style.css

```
body{
  background-color: pink;
}

#overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index 1;
  background-color: plum;
}

#modal{
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
```

modalpopup.php is successfully linked to my style.css file because, I have the body background listed as pink in the main file its included in (javascript.php)and when I click the popup item of my menu the included modalpopup.php displays with the background as pink.

HOWEVER,

I used #overlay and I set the ID's properly but, for some reason when I try and add background colors to these items nothing displays. Any ideas what may be wrong ?

*EDIT*
*I figured it out* I am using XAAMP and I cleared my cache in safari and now it is working.

Comment: How are you trying to add background colors? Can you provide an example with the code that's not working as intended?

Comment: never mind I realize what happened. I use safari and I cleared my cache and now everything is working. I thought it was weird because, I was using XAAMP.

Comment: Certainly stale sheet files will get cached on the client side. Any sane browser will do that, any sane http server will suggest that to the client. That has nothing to do with what browser you use. Remember: if you _test_ then _always_ do so using a fresh anonymous window and _always_ use _deep reloads_ .

Comment: So, incognito mode should work.

Comment: One way around this issue (for your users) is to use a version and increment it for major changes like this  **<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css\?001" type="text/css">**